# Unable to remove CM URL from Google Search console

Tags: content-management, index, sitemap

One of our News article pages is appearing with the `CM` URL in `Google Search results` instead of having a `CD` URL and even after adding "`noindex,nofollow`" meta tags the page still appears. This doesn't occur in `Bing/Yahoo` search.

We tried to refresh the `Google search Results` from Google console by following the below link and did not work.

https://www.sistrix.com/ask-sistrix/google-index-google-bot-crawler/how-can-i-remove-a-url-on-my-website-from-the-google-index

When trying to remove the URL we get a popup saying "`Request URL in the currently selected property or switch properties`"

[image]

We have our live as `sample.com` and the `CM` name would be `xyzcms.sample.com`.

Comment: Hope this link help you `https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20099/unpublished-sitecore-item-in-google-search'

Comment: Actually when trying that I get an error in Google console "Request URL in the currently selected property or switch properties"